# flash to html5, How to

Tags: html, image, audio, canvas, path

I have a good knowladge in web development , But in this situation, I'm trying to find the best way to convert flash site to html5 where it supports in all modern browsers and compatible with iphones and tablets,

http://www.undergroundcathedral.com/

Please do visit the above link, currently it works in flash, I want to convert it into html5, 
I would be glad if any one can suggest me a way of doing it, with complete guidance tutorials, and links,

I drew lines in a html5 canvas but, couldn't find a way to make them anchors. I hope to add onmouseover event to play the sound and to pop up the image,

Suggest me the best way,

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out EaselJS which is an html canvas library.  They have partnered with Adobe in creating a tool called Zoe that converts SWF to spritesheets that can be drawn with EaselJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a good service for this use called [Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/). It is also availible as a plugin for Adobe Flash Studio, if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

From as far as I know Adobe Flash CC has the ability to export, including apps built using ActionScript, into HTML5 + JS + CSS web apps. Take a look > http://tv.adobe.com/watch/creative-cloud-for-web/adobe-flash-professional-cc-overview/